# Issue with certain properties in metaData in node-oracledb

Tags: javascript, proxy, electron, node-oracledb

(I am using node-oracledb thin client v6.2.0)

When I do a simple Select statement like this:

```
connection.execute( mySqlstring, {}, { outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT });
```

The result has metaData like this:

```
  metaData: [
    {
      name: 'ID',
      dbType: [DbType DB_TYPE_NUMBER],
      nullable: false,
      precision: 10,
      scale: 0,
      dbTypeName: 'NUMBER',
      fetchType: [DbType DB_TYPE_NUMBER],
      converter: [Function: converter]
    },
```

But because Electron uses Proxy to send data to the renderer, only valid objects can be send. And `dbType`, `fetchType` and `converter` make this not a valid object.

But I do need the metaData.

This works:

```
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result,null,2));
```

But is of course not what I want.

Should I set other options? Or do I have to write code to exclude these fields?

**Update**

(answers to @christopher-jones)

This is the error I get:

```
Error sending from webFrameMain:  Error: Failed to serialize arguments
    at s.send (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:94175)
    at _.sendToFrame (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:79803)
    at e.reply (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:87292)
...
```

Also I now found out that, looking at it while debugging, that for instance `dbType` is an object:

[image: screenshot dbType in debugger]

I guess I expect that node-oracledb would have an option to output something that could easily be turned into JSON.

This is the code I am executing:

```
export class ControllerDatabaseExecuteSql implements IIpcChannel {

  readonly name: string = ipcChannels.DatabaseExecuteSql;

  async handle(event: IpcMainEvent, id: string | null, args: any[]): Promise<void> {
    event.reply(`${this.name}-#${id}#${ipcReply}`, await _DatabaseExecuteSql( args[0] ));
  }
}
```

So it is the return value of `_DatabaseExecuteSql()` that is sent back using `event.reply()`.

Comment: What is Proxy actually giving - an error message? What does your code look like? Why don't you just construct a simple JS object from the metaData and send that?

Comment: @ChristopherJones See my updates. Converting the metaData is of course possible and not hard to do. But I assumed a thin client for node would have some option that makes returned metaData simply JSON

Comment: Thanks for the details. I would vote against adding a node-oracledb setting for this case, but feel free to open an enhancement request on [GitHub](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues) in case other people also want it.  Depending what the renderer is doing, just extract the parts of the result object you need to send and/or convert to JSON in your app code as you are doing.  If you really don't want the type objects, you could extract type numbers as you saw in the object, e.g. like `result.metaData[0].dbType.num`

Answer (score 0):

So I did what Christopher Jones proposed:

```
res.metaData = metaDataToJson( res.metaData );

[...]

export function metaDataToJson( m: Array<object>) {
  return m.map( (r: any) => 
    ({
      name: r.name, 
      nullable: r.nullable, 
      precision: r.precision,
      scale: r.scale,
      dbTypeName: r.dbTypeName,
    })
  );
}
```